Databricks SQL: IDENTIFIER clause with a backtick string?
Very much an edge case. I was wondering
WITH cte_name (`has_``backticks`) AS (
  VALUES ('value1')
)
SELECT IDENTIFIER(???) FROM cte_name;

Straightforward solutions would be to

not use backticks in your column name
replace IDENTIFIER(???) with `has_``backticks`

However, I'm curious if there's a way to get it to work with IDENTIFIER()
I've tried a bunch of variations of 'IDENTIFIER('has_`backticks')' or 'IDENTIFIER('has_``backticks') and such but they result in SYNTAX errors.
IDENTIFIER clause Databricks docs
